# Customise Office 2010 File > New interface

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

We're in the process of introducing Office 2010 to our 150+ users, replacing Office 2000

We have a strong corporate identity, with a wide range of word templates which our users should be using.

We've setup a Group Policy switching off Blogging and the Office.com templates, and defining the Workgroup Template location, but we were wondering if we could go a bit further...

Having switched off the Office.com templates the **File > New** interface is rather sparse, with only 4 icons displayed.  Additionally our Workgroup Templates are hidden behind **My Templates**.

What we would ideally like to do is display the Workgroup Templates in place of the Office.com templates.  Is this possible?

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Have [discovered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff936214.aspx) that we can use customui xml markup to add to the existing tabs backstage, or to create our own tabs.

Adding the code in the above example to the New tab basically answers the above question, however the button is right at the bottom of the screen.  It looks like there is a blank frame that would naturally hold the Office.com templates still in place.

If anyone knows how to remove *that* we'd appreciate it.